# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php

I get this error message, any help would be appreciated.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
> error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 in
> index.php on line 96
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
> violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near ')' at line 1 in index.php on line 96

This is the code:

```
$centroId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$orderby= 'id DESC';
if (isset($_GET['orderby'])){
    $orderby=filter_var($_GET['orderby'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
$where='';
$search='';
if (isset($_GET['cerca'])){
    $search=filter_var($_GET['cerca'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $where=' AND (cognome like "%'.$search.'%" OR nome like "%'.$search.'%" OR id='.$search.') ';
}
$perpage=3; 
$sql='SELECT count(id) FROM utenti2 WHERE centroId=:centroId AND legge_privacy="SI"  '.$where.'';
$result=$db->prepare($sql);
$result=$db->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':centroId', $centroId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();  //line 96
```

Comment: print_f your sql query _$sql_, how does it look like?

Comment: You should use placeholders for all values, not just `centroId`. `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` does nothing where sql injection is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding quotes around `id=$search`

```
$where=' AND (cognome like "%'.$search.'%" OR nome like "%'.$search.'%" OR id="'.$search.'") ';
```

Answer (score 0):

turn off emulation mode :
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
it's work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).